# Using Geowebcache tiles in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, raster, geoserver

Is there any way to use pre-rendered tiles from inside my GeoServer/data/GeoWebCache as a standalone folder with OpenLayers 3?

GeoWebCache tiling schema is different from classic ZYX.

Is somewhere any script to transform whole structure of tiles to any other schema, which is suitable to use with OpenLayers 3?

Comment: In general you are better off asking questions of a non programming geospatial nature on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, openlayers 3 tag on stackoverflov should be used with everything connected with this library (recommended by developers).

Comment: I recently developed a web app with locally generated GeoWebCache tiles and wrote a blog post. Hope this helps someone. http://yahanistechride.blogspot.com/2015/12/using-geowebcache-cached-tiles-as.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but there is this pull request that implemented it: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3241

Comment: Oh. Looks inactive and closed... Sad. :(